# Jquery not working on route change (Svelte, Sapper)

Tags: jquery, svelte, sapper, svelte-3

im using a datepicker plugin for jquery and it works when the page load first time but when i go to a route the input do not show the datepicker anymore only reloading the page.

```
  onMount(() => {
window.$("#datePick").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
  minDate: new Date(),
  language: "en",
});
window.$("#dateOne").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
  minDate: new Date(),
  language: "en",
}); });
```

thats the code that i run in the component.

also in the template.html a call the javascript files as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/datepicker.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/datepicker.en.js"></script>
```

what im doing wrong ? thanks for your help

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to use Svelte for your datepicker? There's some existing options like [this](https://6edesign.github.io/svelte-calendar/?ref=madewithsvelte.com) and [this](https://github.com/SharifClick/svelte-touch-datepicker). You're killing the benefit of using Svelte by pulling JQuery into your application.

Comment: the first one was not working on sapper so i decided to dont use it the second one i gonna give a try., thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your issue lies at where your `onMount` is defined.

The component may not be destroy / remounted, that's why when you navigate away and back, the function wasn't called, therefore, unable to reinitialise the date picker.

Actually Svelte actions is the best way to integrate with 3rd party API.

```html
<script>
  function jqueryDatePicker(divElem) {
    $(divElem).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
      minDate: new Date(),
      language: "en",
    })
  }
</script>

<div use:jqueryDatePicker />
```

you can check out this ["Introducton to actions"](https://svelte.school/tutorials/introduction-to-actions)